# how to use .contains in Viewbag in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this foreach in my view :

```
@foreach (var partner in ((List<string>)ViewBag.Email))
{
    if (ViewBag.hasFeedback.Contains(partner))
    {

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="partners" value="@partner" checked="checked">
                @ViewBag.FirstName[item] @ViewBag.Lastname[item] ( @partner.ToString() )
            </label>
        </div>
    }
    item += 1;
}
```

In my `ViewBag.hasFeedback` I have array contain strings. How to compare this with variable "partner" how it is shown in code? This example in code doesnt work, because "system.array doesnt contain definition for contains function".

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your `ViewBag.hasFeedback` to a string array first. Like this:

```
@foreach (var partner in ((List<string>)ViewBag.Email))
{
    string[] hasFeedback = string[](ViewBag.hasFeedback);

    if (hasFeedback.Contains(partner))
    {

        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="partners" value="@partner" checked="checked">
                @ViewBag.FirstName[item] @ViewBag.Lastname[item] ( @partner.ToString() )
            </label>
        </div>
    }
    item += 1;
}
```

However, the way you are using ViewBag is a very bad idea. ViewBag is supposed to be used to pass data that is not in your Model to your view. If you have so many data to be passed to your view, you should create a view model.