# Show different button based upon ViewBags passed to Views from Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loops, viewbag

I have created two `ViewBags` which contain different values.

```
ViewBag.attendingEvents = attendingIds;
ViewBag.notAttendingEvent = notAttendingIds;
```

The `attendingIds` contain the ids of all the users which are **attending** the event whereas `notAttendingIds` contain the ids of all the users which are **not attending** the event.

It's showing me too many button since I am looping through. If there are 100 users attending the event then its showing me 100 Remove buttons with one record because the loop. What's the best approach to solve this problem?

```
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @foreach(var record in ViewBag.attendingEvents as IList<User>) {<a href="#"> Remove </a>}
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the Viewbag in the view? Also where is the code for the button you are talking about?

Comment: I missed that. Now I modified my question.

Comment: foreach (var user in Model) is surely not right. Is it foreach (var user in Model.User)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution if I have understood your question correct and if you want only those users who attend the meeting to be able to have the remove button. You need to loop through the result of users and check if they exist in your attendable id list.

```
@foreach (var user in Model.User)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @if(ViewBag.attendingEvents.Contains(user.Id))
            {<a href="#"> Remove </a>}
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem:

It's showing me too many button since I am looping through. If there are 100 users attending the event then its showing me 100 Remove buttons with one record because the loop. What's the best approach to solve this problem?

Best approach or solution:

You are getting the above problem, because there is a foreach to put the button, actually its not neccessary, you simply change your code like below

```
@foreach (var user in Model.User)
{
  <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        string[] Users_attendingEvents = string[](ViewBag.attendingEvents);
        @if(Users_attendingEvents.Contains(user.Id))
            {
                <a href="#"> Remove </a>
             }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

you may also take at look at this link for additional info :[how to use .contains in Viewbag in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117926/how-to-use-contains-in-viewbag-in-asp-net-mvc)

Hope it helps

Thanks